# How I can use font awesome?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

Where is the problem with this code?
It should usually show the phone icon. But it only shows an empty square.

I used to use it in the same way before and had no problem. I recently encountered such a problem.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">

<i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
```

I am in a hurry, please reply quickly.
thank you

Comment: You missed out on providing your code.